# Dynamically create a collection field based on the user response with mongoose in mongo dB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've a database collection where two types of users are there.

**1.Customer:** They will have all the basic functionalities.

**2.Vendor:** They will also have the basic functionalities available in addition they can create, delete, update and get/view the vehicles.

suppose a vendor created a vehicle so a vehicle id will get added to the vendor's collection likewise:

```
{
  . /*other fields*/
  .
  .
  listings: [
   "uniqueId",
   "uniqueId2"
  ]
}
```

I did some searching and found out that to add vehicle Id's to `listings`, the field needs to be created first in `mongoose` otherwise my data will not get inserted in `mongodb` through `mongoose`.
This rises a problem where all the users have `listings` field in them.

So, here's my user model I have created:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_type: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "user type is required!"],
        enum: ["customer", "vendor", "Customer", "Vendor"],
        default: "customer"
    },
    listings: {
        type: Array,
    },//TODO: only create the listings array if the user type is vendor
});
```

So, my question is can I create this `listing` field only if the `user_type` is vendor?

Comment: Defining the field in the schema, doesn't automatically creates it in MongoDB. When you save a document if the listings field is present, then only it will be saved, otherwise, it won't be saved, until and unless you provide a default value.

Comment: well, it does create an empty array and that's what bugging me. The listings array is completely unnecessary for the customer type users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As defined, in the mongoose [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays), Arrays have a default value of [].
So you'll need to override it. Try this:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_type: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "user type is required!"],
        enum: ["customer", "vendor", "Customer", "Vendor"],
        default: "customer"
    },
    listings: {
        type: [String], // can also be ObjectId
        default: undefined
    },
});
```